# Correct way to move to multiple new activites depending on results of Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've done some communication with a server in my AsyncTask. Now depending on that data I want to either go to either Screen A or Screen B. What is the correct way to do this?

Should I call the new activities in the postExcute section? I'm currently on the splash screen.

```
private class CheckLoginDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
                //does stuff before excuting code
        }

        //does the main operation
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)  {

            publishProgress("10", "Checking Login Details Exist . . .");

            if(checkForLogin()){    
                //validate with DB
                publishProgress("20", "Logging in, verifying . . .");
                if(sendforVerif()){
                    publishProgress("100", "You Are Logged In!");

                }else{                  
                    publishProgress("100", "Error Logging In.");

                }

            }else{
                //login or registration required
                publishProgress("100", "Login Required . . .");
            }

            return null;
        }

        //Update Progress       
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            mProgress.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
            statusReadout.setText(values[1]);
        }

        //Update UI with results
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MenuScreen.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

I don't think that is right, plus it doesn't work!?

TIA

Comment: please add full code of Asynctask  class

Comment: Read up on the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation carefully, and use `@Override` annotation to spot the first mistake. The second is that `SplashScreen.class` should be `SplashScreen.this` **only if** this AsyncTask is contained in `SplashScreen` If not, you will need to pass off an Activity/Context instance to this AsyncTask ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are not overriding `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask` Change your code as:

```
private class CheckLoginDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            //does stuff before excuting code
    }

    //does the main operation
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params)  {

             // your code here...
        return null;
    }

    //Update Progress 
@Override     
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
  // your code here...
    }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MenuScreen.class);
        SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I add @Override eclipse tells me to remove it?

Comment: @EricBanderhide : plz add full `AsyncTask` code with question because currently u are trying to Override `onPostExcute()` method but this method not exist in `AsyncTask` . just correct spelling of Execute and use `onPostExecute` instead of `onPostExcute`

Comment: Thanks for this, I have one final question. I want doInBackground to return an int not a string. I thought I should change <Void, String, String> to <Void, String, Int> but this causes all the publishProgress calls to be invalid?

Comment: I should also add, it works if its Integer but not if its Int, what is that about?

Comment: Change `<Void, String, String>` to `<Void, String, Integer>` , `protected String doInBackground(Void... params)` to `protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)` and `onPostExecute(String result )` to `onPostExecute(Integer result )`